# Laravel 5.6 Routing - Force language in the URL

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I am creating a multilingual app with Laravel 5.6.

I want to force anything the URL to specifically use the language parameter.

e.g

```
www.myapps.com/something/somethingelse/andmore...

would redirect to

www.myapps.com/**en**/something/somethingelse/andmore...
```

So far,

I have used  :

```
  Route::prefix('{lang}')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('welcome');
    Route::get('/XYZ', 'HomeController@XXXXFunction')->name('another');
  });
```

But how do I force a redirect to a the language?